# Razor Pages routing with a prefix id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Is there a way with Razor Pages to solve this :

I have a user that is part of two companies :
These companies have id 1 and 2

My Razor Pages app has these pages :

```
Pages/Index.cshtml

Pages/Account/Login.cshtml
Pages/Account/Logout.cshtml

Pages/Dashboard/Index.cshtml
Pages/Employees/Index.cshtml
```

What I want to achieve is this :

For this pages, I want to have the regular routes

```
Pages/Index.cshtml

Pages/Account/Login.cshtml
Pages/Account/Logout.cshtml
```

For this pages, I want the route to be `/[COMPANY_ID]/Dashboard` or `/[COMPANY_ID]/Employees`

```
Pages/Dashboard/Index.cshtml
Pages/Employees/Index.cshtml
```

On the `Pages/Index.cshtml` the user can chose to go the dashboard of the company with id 1 or 2.

On the `Pages/Dashboard/Index.cshtml` I want to create a link to `Pages/Employees/Index.cshtml`, how to make sure that the right `[COMPANY_ID]` is added automatically ?

Thanks

Comment: you have to look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For pages `Pages/Dashboard/Index.cshtml` and `Pages/Employees/Index.cshtml`, I want the route to be `/[COMPANY_ID]/Dashboard` or `/[COMPANY_ID]/Employees`

> On the Pages/Dashboard/Index.cshtml I want to create a link to Pages/Employees/Index.cshtml, how to make sure that the right [COMPANY_ID] is added automatically ?

To achieve the above requirement, you can try:

*add and configure route to your page(s)*

```
services
    .AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Dashboard/Index", "/{id:int}/Dashboard/Index");
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Employees/Index", "/{id:int}/Employees/Index");
    });
```

*in `Dashboard/Index.cshtml` page*

```
@page
@model xxx.Pages.Dashboard.IndexModel
@{
    var hasId = HttpContext.Request.RouteValues.TryGetValue("id", out object id);
}

<h1>Dashboard Index</h1>

<a href=@(@hasId ? $"/{id}/Employees/Index" : "/Employees/Index")>Employees Index</a>
```

Test Result

[image]